# Issue in creating a file and writing content into it in azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am writing an azure function for creating and uploading text on azure storage but I got error 500 Internal server error. Below is my code of the azure function.

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using System;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string strFileName = "321rahila.csv";//req.Query["name"];
    string Content ="Hello File";

    //string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
   // dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
   // strFileName = strFileName ?? data?.strFileName;
    string StorageAccountName = "xyz";
    string StorageKey = "i0PNZ6Ykse7oSSfUzFeA36rQfAv9UZnJ5wybQWh5Jol0NRM4sal4s8B3ipkjvfzcsP8/gnI6A==";`enter code here`
    string strShareName = "lables";
        //string StorageScheme = "SharedKey";
    // string FileEndPoint = string.Format("https://{0}.file.core.windows.net/", StorageAccountName);
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, StorageKey), true);
    var fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    var share = fileClient.GetShareReference(strShareName);
   // if (share.Exists())
    {
       var rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
       CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference(strFileName);
       var fileToCreate = rootDir.GetFileReference(strFileName);
       **fileToCreate.UploadText(Content);**
    }

    return strFileName != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {strFileName}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

I get the error when I uncomment the line fileToCreate.UploadText(Content); and without it I am unable to create a file and upload text into it. The same is working fine on visual studio.

Comment: Suppose your are using the linux Function, right?

Comment: No i am using Windows azure function. Have wrote this code on azure function online @George Chen

Comment: I think you need to use "Microsoft.Azure.Storage" and "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File" module but not "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" and "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File".

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using output bindings? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=csharp#output---example

Comment: This is an azure function and i can only add reference . The same is working on visual studio, so i want an azure solution that will work on azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the Azure Function in the portal could not find the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` package. The right way is to create `project.json` file and reference NuGet package explicitly. The below is my project.json file.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage": "9.3.3"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Then in the run.csx use the assembly.

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
```

And the below is my work code.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    string strFileName = "321rahila.csv";//req.Query["name"];
    string Content ="Hello File";


    string StorageAccountName = "my account";
    string StorageKey = "my key";
    string strShareName = "windows";
    //string StorageScheme = "SharedKey";
    // string FileEndPoint = string.Format("https://{0}.file.core.windows.net/", StorageAccountName);
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, StorageKey), true);
    var fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    var share = fileClient.GetShareReference(strShareName);
    // if (share.Exists())
    {
        var rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference(strFileName);
        var fileToCreate = rootDir.GetFileReference(strFileName);
        await fileToCreate.UploadTextAsync(Content); 
    }

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

Hope this could help you.